# RAIM Checks when using GNSS in lieu of DME for distance information

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, gnss, instrument-approaches, raim

I understand that a RAIM has to be checked on the ground as part of preflight, as well as before the commencement of an RNAV/RNP approach.

What I am unable to find information on online, is whether a RAIM Prediction check has to be done on any other non precision approaches if we are using the GNSS in lieu of DME for distance information?